# Is there a way to link a file in js to another js file ? Code snippets below

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, firebase

So basically a button in Res after Sign in should put a real time chat on screen. Res contains two buttons Sign Out and Chat. Why isn't the Press button in Res to call Chat not calling Chat?
If Anyone can help that would be great! PS I'm a newbie to React.

App.js file here

```js
import Res from './components/Res';
import Chat from './components/Chat';
import Signin from './components/Signin';
import './App.css';
import {auth} from './firebase.js'
import {useAuthState} from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'
import Router from './Router'


function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth)
  return (
    <>
      {user ? <Res/> : <Signin/>} //After you sign in it goes to Res
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Res.js file here

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Routes, Route, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core'
import { auth } from '../firebase.js'
import Signin from './Signin';
import Signout from './Signout';
import {useAuthState} from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Chat from './Chat'


function Res() {

    
    return (
        
    <div>
        
        <button onClick={()=><Chat/>} >Press</button> //I want it to call the javascript file Chat

        <Signout/>
        
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default Res
```

Chat.js file here

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect,useRef} from 'react'
import { db, auth } from '../firebase'
import Sendmessage from './Sendmessage'
import Signout from './Signout'

function Chat() {
  

  const scroll = useRef()
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  useEffect(
    ()=>{
      db.collection('message').orderBy('createdAt').limit(50).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
  })
}, [])
  return (
    
    <div id = "chat">
      
      <Signout/>
      
      <div className="msgs">
      {messages.map(({id,text,photoURL,uid})=>(
        <div>

        <div key={id} className={`msg ${uid == auth.currentUser.uid ?'sent':'received'}`}>
          <img src = {photoURL} alt = ""/>
          <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      ))}
      </div>
      <Sendmessage scroll />
      <div ref = {scroll}></div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Chat
```

Not sure why the press button does nothing

Comment: You cannot call a javascript file. You can add your Chat component to your Routes and use react Navigation API (in case you are using v6 - https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate ). If you only need to show a Chat inside the Res component - then you need to declare a boolean variable with useState hook, change button click function to set this state variable to true and write the conditional component render in your JSX markup. If you have other questions/issues - feel free to modify your question and include more details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used useState and got it working